# Import to Entityform via Feeds? Feeds entity processor module?

Tags: entities, feeds, importing-exporting

I've built an [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) and now would like to use [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) importer to add entries. Feeds does not seem to offer a processor for Entityform. I've done some digging and found the [Feeds entity processor](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_entity_processor) module.

Will this module allow me to target my Entityform via a Feeds importer?

The Feeds entity processor page offers this info:

> This module provides a generic processor for all entity types that
>   support CRUD operations through the Entity API module.

I've done some digging into this too, but can't quite determine if this will do what I need. If there are other ways/modules that will help, I'm all ears!

---

**FYI:** *Due to restrictions in my development environment, I can't simply give it try (wish I could!). I need to make requests for new modules to be installed... so I need to be pretty darn sure something is going to do what I need before I make the request.*

Comment: I haven't used Entityform and the Feeds entity processor doesn't guarantee that it will work for all entity types. The only way to find out if it works is to try it out. It sounds very disruptive that you are not allowed to try out possible solutions. Perhaps you could try https://simplytest.me/ for trying it out. I also recommend to use the Feeds Import Preview module for testing.

Comment: @MegaChriz I just went ahead and requested the module without testing... sometimes you just need to take a chance. And it worked! I added an answer to my own question... just in case anyone else is in the same predicament.

Comment: Ah great! Thanks for letting me know in case I'll be using Entityform in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**CONFIRMED!** Feeds entity processor module will allow importing directly into an Entity form via a feeds importer.

Comment: what did you use for the Date submitted default value? Any combo of date formats I use doesn't work.